# Need guard clause syntax for this list comprehension using do notation

Tags: haskell, purescript

I found this function in a [pure script tutorial](https://try.purescript.org/?github=purescript%2Ftrypurescript%2Fmaster%2Fclient%2Fexamples%2FDoNotation.purs&session=8d19f3d8-656e-b5e0-99d4-766c0d29671f) and I'm trying to convert to Haskell because sometimes it would be nice to do complicated list comprehension in this way, I think. I'm stuck on the guard line (commented out) that only lets right angle triangles through to the solution set.

```
triples :: Int -> [[Int]]
triples n = do
  z <- [1 .. n]
  y <- [1 .. z]
  x <- [1 .. y] 
--  guard x * x + y * y == z * z ↼↽ not sure how to do this
  return [x, y, z]
```

in purescript:

```
-- Find Pythagorean triples using an array comprehension.
triples :: Int -> Array (Array Int)
triples n = do
  z <- 1 .. n
  y <- 1 .. z
  x <- 1 .. y
  guard $ x * x + y * y == z * z
  pure [x, y, z]
```

Comment: I tried using a comma a la [2 * x | x <- [1..10], even x]  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is nearly the same code:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

triples :: Int -> [[Int]]
triples n = do
  z <- [1 .. n]
  y <- [1 .. z]
  x <- [1 .. y] 
  guard $ x * x + y * y == z * z
  return [x, y, z]
```

Just remember to import `guard`. Note that, in this case you can pretend that `guard` is defined as:

```
guard :: Bool -> [()]
guard True  = [()]
guard False = []
```

The library definition is more general, but it does not matter here. In principle, you could even use this definition for `guard` and avoid importing from the library.

Comment: Error using the guard definition above: 
`    • Could not deduce (Monad m0)
      from the context: Monad m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   guard :: forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => Bool -> [()]
        at codewars.hs:108:10-32
      The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘guard’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature: guard :: Monad m => Bool -> [()]
    |
108 | guard :: Monad m => Bool -> [()]
`

Comment: importing guard from Control.Monad worked fine.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil, the `Monad m` constraint was superfluous, fixed

Comment: without `import Control.Monad` eye would write `_<-[1|x*x+y*y=z*z]`.